# Calling two controller methods from script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call two methods in my controller. One that starts a conversion and one that returns the percentage of the conversion to the view to update a progressbar. The conversion is started by a post by clicking the button "startConversion" before the getPercentage function is called. However, only the conversion starts while the percentage function wont. I have tried starting the percentage function first and it works, but after I press the conversion button the setTimeout stops and it wont update anymore.

Does anyone have a suggestion what can be wrong and any way to fix it?

```
//View
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(window).load(function () {
        startConvert();
    });

    function startConvert() {
        document.getElementById("startConversion").click()
        getPercentage();
    }

    function getPercentage() {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetPercentage","File")",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#div').html(result);
                    var r = result;
                    progressBarSim(r);
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert("Fail");
                }
            });
        setTimeout(getPercentage, 500);
    }

</script>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">         
    <input id="startConversion" type="Submit"  name="Convert" />
</form>

//FileController
[HttpPost]
public double GetPercentage() {
    return enc.Percent;
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Convert()
{
... //Removed
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are submitting your form which basically causes the browser to load a new page (whatever the result of the form action is), and this is why the getPercentage() method never seems to be called.

The easiest approach is to submit your form using ajax, however it seems like you want the user to upload files, which can't be submitted via ajax.

I would thus suggest setting a target on the form to an invisible iframe on the page.  This will make the form submit to that iframe (so the result will be loaded in the iframe, and not cause a new page to be loaded in the main window).

ie, something like:

```
  <iframe name="uploadTarget" src="" style="position:absolute;left:-9999px"></iframe>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="uploadTarget">
  ... etc ...
```

If you want to track the progress of the actual upload, then you need to look at other options such as using http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Edit: To submit the form using ajax:

```
function startConvert() {
    var form = $("#startConversion").closest("form");
    $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serializeArray());
    getPercentage();
}
```

Comment: The file I want to convert is already uploaded, and the button is just a way to automatically start the conversion after redirect from upload. Do you have an example of submitting the form using ajax?

Comment: Updated answer as requested

Comment: The iframe solution fixed the problem! Thanks Martin! One more thing though; I used to redirect to another page in my Convert method when the conversion is done (return RedirectToAction("/Download/" + result);), but now it just skips it and stays on the same page. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try calling `setInterval(getPercentage, 500);` inside the `startConvert` method itself, instead of `setTimeout` again and again.

Comment: Tried both. Same problem with either solution.